# “Each party must not” - grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I know that the above phrase is commonly used in legal documents, but I’ve been told that the above phrase is grammatically incorrect or clunky. What do you think? If so, how would you change it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This sentence is grammatically correct but does sound a little bit clunky. It's not essential to change it, but if you wanted to you could say "Neither party shall" (if there's two parties) or "The parties must not". I think the issue is the "Each" at the start which makes it sound clunky. Either way, the original sentence is still grammatically correct and formal.
Hope this helps!

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks!

Comment: The risk of rephrasing is that in legal terminology words and phrases can carry additional meanings to the plain English equivalents. So "The parties must not" might not carry exactly the same legal meaning as "Each party must not".

Comment: This answer is merely an expression of opinion, unsupported in any way. It may or may not be correct, but the poster (nor anybody else) has no basis on which to decide. Please finish the Tour and read the Help on answering questions to find out how this site works.

Comment: @Alaina - Welcome to the site!

Comment: @TechnoCat thank you!

Comment: @KillingTime - As someone who's spent 20+ years in corporate law and legislation, I'm confident in saying that the "risk of rephrasing" by non-lawyers is an overblown risk promulgated by lawyers to keep them in business and maintain their high fees.  Where really difficult and technical matters are involved, sure, it's essential to have the drafting done by a professional.  However, in the majority of contracts, changes can safely be made by a lay person - so long as that lay person is very careful and very thoughtful (and consults with lawyers on any risky issue).

Comment: Adding to @Alaina's answer, there's a legal difference between "Neither/no party shall ..." and "The parties shall not ..".  Some contracts impose obligations on each party "**severally**" while others impose obligations **jointly**.  E.g. if two people own a property together, then their mortgage contract might say "**The parties must** make mortgage repayments ...".  In other cases, a contract imposes *separate* responsibilities for each party to a contract.  The bottom line is that, legally, the two terms ""Neither party shall" and "The parties must not" are legally very different!